Special case of sifting property of dirac-delta at singularity.
Note: This is not a duplicate. You can see my linked old question below in the text and realize that my question is different.
I have an integral of the following form:
$$
I = \lim_{a\ \to\ \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|t|} \operatorname{csc}(t)^2 \left[\frac{\sin(at)}{at} - \frac{\sin((a+2)t)}{(a+2)t}\right]{\rm d}t
$$
I want to express this Integral in a closed form (no summations) $\color{red}{\text{or a series expansion at} \ a=\infty}$.
My thoughts/attempts:

I tired to make use of the sifting property of dirac-delta operator, where the $\operatorname{sinc}$ function kernel approaches a dirac-delta.
I realized that there is a singularity at the sifting point ( i.e. $t = 0$ ), so I am not able to apply it.
I am definitely aware that if  we split the integral into two separate ones, we will run into the issues pointed HERE.
But this is a difference between two very close kernels and I already think that it is possible to express the  combined integral in terms of $a$, but don't know what that is ( I am omitting the background knowledge for now, but consider this information optional ).

Question: Is there a way to formulate an expression using the sifting property for this special case despite the singularity ?.

What do you mean by expressing $\lim_{a\to\infty}f(a)$ in a closed form in terms of $a$? The limit, if it exists, does not depend on $a$.

@Gonçalo, alright, let me be wrong about my claim. If you have any thoughts on how to express such a limit independent of a, please go ahead. Much appreciated.

It's not a question of being right or wrong, but of being clear. Do you want to compute the integral in closed form, or do you want to compute the limit of the integral as $a\to\infty$? Please edit your question to clarify this point.

I edited it. Hopefully it is clear. The closed form is for  the limit of the integral
